# Where can I find MasterApiEntity.msg and MasterApi.msg from ARNI Package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to evaluate the ARNI, but after cloning the project on my pc I am not able to build/start the gui or arni_processing as those two messages are missing in the repo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221625/where-can-i-find-masterapientity.msg-and-masterapi.msg-from-arni-package?/) by [pace](https://answers.ros.org/users/25188/pace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, sorry to answer you such late, I haven't seen your question before. You can find those under arni_msgs but I think your problem is another. After downloading the package into your workspace you have to recompile it with catkin_make to generate the msg files. Then it will probably work. You can find more information on catkin here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials
I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) with karma: 70 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0